# Trying to build/install patched gtk3-engines-oxygen to test bugfix, get shared changelog.Debian.gz is different from other instances of package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, patch, debuild

I want to just quickly test [the patch in this bug report to `gtk3-engines-oxygen`](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333983) so it can go upstream. I could test it either temporarily or permanently; I would just like to do it. I currently have the package installed. So far, I've tried:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/o # keep everything self-contained
$ cd /tmp/o
$ apt-get source gtk3-engines-oxygen
$ cd oxygen-gtk3-1.3.5/
$ patch -p1 < /path/to/patchfile
$ dpkg-source --commit # to make debuild happy
(name 'layout'; just save the default; this is a test)
$ debuild -us -uc # bypass signature checks
$ sudo debi ../oxygen-gtk3_1.3.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.changes
```

According to some people on #ubuntu-packaging, this is what I have to do. It's this last step that's the problem; I'm getting

```
(Reading database ... 503333 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gtk3-engines-oxygen_1.3.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gtk3-engines-oxygen:amd64 (1.3.5-0ubuntu1) over (1.3.5-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gtk3-engines-oxygen_1.3.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/gtk3-engines-oxygen/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package gtk3-engines-oxygen:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gtk3-engines-oxygen_1.3.5-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
debi: debpkg -i failed
```

What's going on? How do I fix it? Or am I doing this completely wrong (and ergo so are they)?

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04 amd64. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest just using `dpkg -i filename.deb`, but know that if you want to go back to the default version, you would have to do `apt-get install --reinstall gtk3-engines-oxygen`. On an unrelated note, you might want to create a changelog entry in `debian/changelog` so that you know that this is your version.

Comment: Totally missed the deb file somehow, derp; alas, same error. Updating the question text to address this. Thanks in the meantime!

Comment: Er disregard; using `--force-all` did it. Bug verified as fixed with patch. Can you repaste that comment as an answer so I can check it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest just using `dpkg -i filename.deb`, but know that if you want to go back to the default version, you would have to do `apt-get install --reinstall gtk3-engines-oxygen`.

On an unrelated note, you might want to create a changelog entry in `debian/changelog` so that you know that this is your version.